# StanfordDependencyParser returns all labels as NULL in german

Tags: nltk, dependency-parsing

I'm trying to get the StanfordDependencyParser in NLTK to run with german.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser

dep_parser = StanfordDependencyParser('../Stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/stanford-parser.jar',
                                  '../Stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/stanford-parser-3.6.0-models.jar',
                                      model_path='edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/germanPCFG.ser.gz')
result = dep_parser.raw_parse("Deutschland ist ein foederal verfasster Staat in Mitteleuropa, der aus den 16 deutschen Laendern gebildet wird.")
dep = result.next()
print dep.to_dot()
```

I can generate a tree, but all dependencies are labled as NULL.

```
digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]

0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 2 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (Deutschland)"]
2 [label="2 (ist)"]
2 -> 1 [label="NULL"]
2 -> 6 [label="NULL"]
2 -> 18 [label="NULL"]
3 [label="3 (ein)"]
4 [label="4 (foederal)"]
4 -> 5 [label="NULL"]
5 [label="5 (verfasster)"]
6 [label="6 (Staat)"]
6 -> 3 [label="NULL"]
6 -> 4 [label="NULL"]
6 -> 7 [label="NULL"]
6 -> 9 [label="NULL"]
6 -> 17 [label="NULL"]
7 [label="7 (in)"]
7 -> 8 [label="NULL"]
8 [label="8 (Mitteleuropa)"]
9 [label="9 (,)"]
10 [label="10 (der)"]
11 [label="11 (aus)"]
11 -> 12 [label="NULL"]
11 -> 13 [label="NULL"]
11 -> 14 [label="NULL"]
11 -> 15 [label="NULL"]
12 [label="12 (den)"]
13 [label="13 (16)"]
14 [label="14 (deutschen)"]
15 [label="15 (Laendern)"]
16 [label="16 (gebildet)"]
16 -> 11 [label="NULL"]
17 [label="17 (wird)"]
17 -> 10 [label="NULL"]
17 -> 16 [label="NULL"]
18 [label="18 (.)"]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It works when switching to english. Does german not support Dependency parsing?

Comment: you're using the english model to tag german.

Comment: I am using the german model "germanPCFG" (see line 5), when using the english model I get labels, but they are wrong as the text is german

Comment: @Denny I have the same problem in French. Did you successfully solved it? Thanks!